# obstacle avoidance with navigation stack

Tags: ros, navigation, local-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm running the navigation stack and using rviz 2DNav to send goal to my robot but it don't avoid obstacles.
I'm sure thta it detects them because they're displayed when I use the grid cells display with the obstacles and inflated obstacles topic.
What could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42924/obstacle-avoidance-with-navigation-stack/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-05**:
I've noticed that, using 2DNav from rviz, the /goal topic published by rviz is subscribed by the proxy node and not by the move_base node, which is the one that published on /cmd_vel. Could this be an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With move_base you can visualize local or global costmap.

If you are seeing the global one, it comes only from you map, not from your sensors.
If you cannot see the local costmap obstacles, then your problem may be with the configurations of your yaml files.
cheers

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2012-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2012-09-04**:
I can see the local costmap obstacles, to do that i'm using two grid cell display setting each topic to /move_base/local_costmap/obstacles and /move_base/local_costmap/inflated_obstacles. But also if I can see the obstacles the robot doesn't avoid them. I can't figure why.